# QByteArray to short Int array in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, short, qbytearray

I am receiving a QByteArray from UDP Socket. The QByteArray is of 52 elements each containing values from 0 to 9 - A to F. Now, I want to convert this QByteArray into a short int array of 13 elements such that first 4 elements of the QByteArray are stored in first element of short int array.

Eg. QByteArray = (002400AB12CD) -> ShortINT = [0024,00AB,12CD]

I have tried concatenating 4 elements and then convert them to Short INT.

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be? for a short you can only have a max bit of 16. so you can represent the value as either 0 to 65535 or -32768 to 32767. 65535 which is in bytes is FFFF for unsigned.

Comment: Unsigned short will be fine. I just want each element to contain 2 bytes of data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QByteArray::data()` and `QByteArray::constData()` to access pointer to stored data and use c cast or reinterp_cast to cast specific type. Also you need to know endianness of data is it big-endian or little endian.

```cpp
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtEndian>

void test() {
    QByteArray data("\x00\x24\x00\xAB\x12\xCD", 6);
    qint16_be* p = (qint16_be*) data.data();
    int l = data.size() / sizeof(qint16_be);
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
        qDebug() << i << hex << p[i];
    }
}
```

Qt 4 does not have `_be` types. You can use `qFromBigEndian` or `qbswap` to swap bytes.

```cpp
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtEndian>

void test() {
    QByteArray data("\x00\x24\x00\xAB\x12\xCD", 6);
    qint16* p = (qint16*) data.data();
    int l = data.size() / sizeof(qint16);
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
        qDebug() << i << hex << qFromBigEndian(p[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just wanted to ask about the equivalent function/type to qint16_be for QT 4.7.4.

Comment: qt 4 has `T qFromLittleEndian<T>(const uchar* data)` and `qFromBigEndian` template functions defined in <QtCore/qendian.h>